# Reversing Stereo Output in Android

Tags: android, audio

I use my phone with a lot of different audio devices with different configurations, and for some of them  the stereo channels are sometimes reversed (like if with my back to the speakers rather than facing them, etc.)

I wanted to write an xposed module that flips/reverses the stereo channels, but found I have no idea where to even begin.

The AudioManager class doesn't seem to address stereo channels, and after digging around and finding nothing elsewhere I'm starting to think this may be more of a hardware kernel feature - and thus not accessible through xposed (read: system code).

Does anyone have any light to shed on the matter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it would be much simpler to take a soldering iron and add some switches to your audio wires which simply switch the speakers.

Comment: That's not very helpful. My car speakers aren't reversed, my bedroom speakers are, my bluetooth headphones sometimes and sometimes aren't - it's not a physical issue - it's something, for example, that's easily doable on a PC.

Comment: It's a comment what do you expect ;-) However I mean that seriosly. There are some 6 pole switches that should be done easily. Okay I see I got it wrong... I read for my like I have one pair of speakers where I want to reverse the order.

Comment: I guess I failed to define my actual problem in the original post, I apologize for sounding ungrateful. I'll rewrite it to be more clear. Thanks anyway.